# How to make a service running on an EC2 instance be available to my team (having the same AWS account) via a URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

So, I have created an EC2 instance and I'm running a service on port 8088. For now, I'm using SSH to connect to it, with the following command :

`ssh -i "~/Downloads/my_key.pem" -L 8087:127.0.0.1:8088 ec2-user@x.xxx.xx.xx`

After starting the service on port 8088, I run `localhost:8087` on my browser to interact with the service.

However, I want this service to be available to everyone having access to this AWS account. Basically, one shouldn't have to SSH to this and then be able to see it on their browser. I intend to create a URL for accessing this service. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do same, but through some bastion host. So your team can ssh tunnel to the website through bastion, rather then through your actual ec2 server. Otherwise setup VPN for your team memebrs.

Comment: How do you define "everyone having access to this AWS account"? Should they be authenticated via their AWS credentials, or by the fact that they have the PEM file for the instance? Are all these users connected via a common network, or do you want them to connect from different locations across the Internet? Does the service itself include any authentication, so you could make it public?

Comment: Users should be authenticated via their AWS credentials. They are also connected via VPN, so the service doesn't need to be public

Comment: If they are connected via VPN, why do you need to use the SSH Tunnel? Can't they just connect directly to the instance on port 8088?